# How can I extract time information from excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a large data in excel with, 02:12 format. I want to find out the time difference between cells in minutes. Like cell A2-> 02:12 cell B2-> 02:20 now I want 08 in another cell using formula B2-A2. But the formula is incorrect. 
Can anyone suggest me something to solve the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want:

```
=TEXT(B2-A2,"h:mm")
```

if you just want to display the value and not calculate again. Better is to select the fields A2, B2, C2, Right-click and select "Format cells...", set category to Time, and Type to hh:mm through the gui. Then as was noted below, you can continue to use the time in further calculations.

Comment: After converting cell value into time, should I try =B2-A2??

Comment: Jeramy, why would you turn the result of the calculation into text? That will render it useless for further calculations, like average processing time or some such. Just formatting the cell will be sufficient.

Comment: @teylyn, Can you explain how?

Comment: @ubuntu explain how *what*? Format a cell? Respond to my answer if it is not clear.

Comment: @teylyn, good point. I was assuming he was just displaying the result. I updated my response.

Comment: Jeramy, that does not make sense. Formatting a cell with Text() in it as time will not do anything useful. Your formula is the problem.

Comment: @teylyn I tested it in my system prior to posting and it produces acceptable results. I also find reference on Microsoft's website to the same format: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Calculate-the-difference-between-two-times-e1c78778-749b-49a3-b13e-737715505ff6 If there is additional reason not to use the format, please let me know and I will not suggest it in the future. Thanks!

Comment: @Jeramy, the article first mentions the regular way with formatting the cell. I just don't see why you would want to convert numbers into text for no apparent reason. It does not add anything useful, it only removes functionality.

Comment: I agree 100%, that is the better method which is why I said that in the answer. The OP asked "I want 08 in another cell using formula B2-A2" which the formula also does, and is a quick way to get the result without going through the UI. Thank you for the comments though, if another user comes along looking for the answer I think this conversation will make very clear the benefits of the UI method.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your cell values are real time values and not text.

Then you can just subtract `=B2-A2` and format the result with the desired number format.

If the calculation does not work, the cells are not numeric and you need to convert them.